# WPF grid visibility on button click

Tags: wpf, visibility, wpf-grid

I have a WPF application. If I write only grid hide show on button click then it is working. But if I write any code below that, it is not working.

```
<Grid Margin="0">
    <Grid x:Name="nonLoading" Margin="0" Visibility="{Binding Path=GridVisibility}">
    </Grid>
```

```
private Visibility _gridVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    public Visibility GridVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _gridVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            _gridVisibility = value;
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://www.daedtech.com/wpf-and-notifying-property-change/ you need to implement INotifyPropertyChange interface to update UI when you change binding

Answer (score 1):

Please implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspxhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface

```
private Visibility _gridVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
public Visibility GridVisibility
{
    get
    {
        return _gridVisibility;
    }
    set
    {
        _gridVisibility = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```